# Why is it easier to throw electrons from a higher energy shell?

Tags: electrostatics, atomic-physics, potential-energy, orbitals, ionization-energy

From what i understand, as we increase the radius of unlike charges, the potential energy of the system also increases, so electrons in the outer shell live in a higher potential system, i.e more force is required to break them apart as compared to electrons closer to the nucleus, so why is it easier for electrons in outer shells to move away from the atom

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think about this is to think about how much energy does it take to launch a rocket off earth. Less energy is needed if it is already higher up (i.e. at a higher potential energy) then if it is lower.

For a more mathematical basis, as the unlike charges move apart the potential energy of the system goes to some constant (which we can say is zero). If they are not at infinity then they have a smaller potential which goes as $-\frac{1}{r^{2}}$. So if $r$ is larger then this is closer to zero, and you need less energy to separate the electron from the outer shell (where on average $r$ is larger) then from a closer shell.

Comment: is there any way for it to be intuitive or is it a concept best understood through math.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer starts to get it, but the fundamental confusion is the *reference.*

Remember that the electrostatic potential energy is a $1/r$ form, and therefore is nonzero out to infinity. So when we talk about breaking an electron "free from a nucleus" we're saying "what does it take to get the electron to *infinity*?"

And the exact amount of work it takes to get a charge from its current position $r$ (relative to the nucleus, say at the origin) is exactly $k_e e^2/r$. Notice that this gets *smaller* as $r$ gets larger: it takes less work to free an electron the further away it is.

Your intuition is good but just need a little refining, in the following way. You're thinking that as the electron moves away from the nucleus its potential energy increases... but increases *relative to what*? "Relative to where it was before"? Absolutely.

Relative to the potential at infinity? No. It actually *decreases* relative to the potential at infinity. In the usual form, $U(r)=-k_e e^2/r$ which gets *closer to zero* as $r$ increases.

And remember, when you talk about "freeing" the electron, you're talking about getting it to infinity. So the potential at infinity is the reference point you care about, *not* wherever it was before it got further away.

The "potential difference increases means more force" intuition you have is spot on. It's just the reference point you have to think about.